# Name error while using Multiple modules and Pyqt

Tags: python, multithreading, module, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to create a login system using pyqt and i have multiple modules, here's part of my code below from my settings module:

```
class User(object):
        def __init__(self, fname, lname, dob, gender):
                self.firstname = fname
                self.lastname = lname
                self._dob = dob
                self.gender = gender
                self.type = 'General'
                self._username = ''
                self._hashkey = ''

        def Report(self):
                print("Full Name: {0} {1}\nDate of Birth: {2}\nGender: {3}\nAccess Level: {4}".format(self.firstname,self.lastname, self._dob, self.gender, self.type))
                print(self._username)

        def Genusername(self):
                self._username = str(str(self._dob)[:2] + self.firstname[:2] + self.lastname[:2])
                saveUsers(users)

        def Verify(self, Username, Password):
                if Password == self._hashkey:
                        return True
                else:
                        return False

def verifyUser(Username, Password):
        for user in users:
                if Username == user._username:
                        if user.Verify(Username, Password):
                                print('Login Successful')
                        else:
                                print('Wrong Password')
                else:
                        print('User does not exist')    

if __name__ == '__main__':
        users = []
        loadUsers(users)
```

and here's my pyqt gui module which is what im trying to test:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import Settings

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.lbl1 = QtGui.QLabel('Username')
        self.lbl2 = QtGui.QLabel('Password')
        self.username = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.password = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        self.okButton = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
        self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.Login)
        self.cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(self.lbl1, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.username, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.lbl2, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.password, 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.okButton, 3, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.cancelButton, 3, 0)

        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Login')
        self.show()

    def Login(self):
        Settings.verifyUser(self.username.text(),self.password.text())

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Loginwindow = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm trying to get the username and password from the pyqt edit widget and verify them with the username and password with the users, the users are all classes which are stored in a list and dumped as a pickle file which load up, i keep getting a name error for the verify function of my code and i have no idea how to get the list to go into the function, i tried other ways but not working, If there's another method for structuring my code or using pyqt please let me know, I'm new to PyQt and when it comes to using modules

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ProgramA\LoginGUI.py", line 39, in Login
    Settings.verifyUser(self.username.text(),self.password.text())
  File "C:\Users\ProgramA\Settings.py", line 78, in verifyUser
    for user in users:
NameError: name 'users' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `users = []` is inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"`, block, so it won't be executed when you import Settings, so `users` won't exist in that case.  (It probably doesn't make sense to have `users` be a global variable defined in the settings module in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

The `users` object doesn't exist as a global nor as a local in `verifyUser` (when a module is imported the `__name__` is not `__main__`). Best would be to create it in the UI and pass it as parameter to `verifyUser`:

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        
        self.initUI()
        self.users = []

    ...

    def Login(self):
        Settings.verifyUser(self.username.text(),self.password.text(), self.users)
```

and in `Settings.py` define

```
def verifyUser(Username, Password, users):
```

Comment: I have another question but i can't type it here, its too long lol, email?